# Binding Deezer iOS SDK (Objective-C) into a Xamarin (C#) app

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, deezer

I'm developing a cross-platform mobile application, using Xamarin (with Xamarin Studio version 6.0.2). 
I'm focusing on the iOS Part first.
I want to implement the Deezer SDK in my app
As the SDK is delivered is Objective-C, I need to bind it to C#, and this is where I have troubles.

I use Xamarin’s tool Objective Sharpie 3.3.0p, based on this walkthrough in order to generate the files ApiDefinition.cs and Structs.cs https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/.

Here is the details of what I did:

1) I downloaded the iOS SDK on Deezer developers website

2) I created an iOS Binding Library project on Xamarin

3) I used the FAT library file "libDeezer.a" as a native reference.

4) I ran the following command line:

```
sharpie bind -output ./DeezerAPI -namespace DeezerAPI -sdk iphoneos9.3 ./deezer-ios-sdk-v0/DeezerSDK/include/*.h
```

Note that I didn’t only try with targeting *.h. In fact, in the walkthrough it is said that I should target the top-level header file.
So I read carefully through those header files, and I couldn’t find a unique top-level header file. Actually, it came out to me that there are 6 top-level header files, as they are not called by any other header file.

- Deezer+Compatibility.h
- DZRGenericCancelable.h
- DZRPlayableArray.h
- DZRPlayer.h
- DZRRequestManager.h
- NSBundle+DZRBundle.h

I tried to target each of these files, separately and together. 
The command worked well each time and delivered the ApiDefinition.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs files.

5) I copied and pasted the content of these files in the corresponding files of the Binding project, and merging the original "using" with the generated ones.

6) I tried to build the project and a bunch of errors came out.

Here are the errors that I have:

- The type or namespace '$name' could not be found. Are you missing any
  assembly reference ?  with $name as (BaseType, Abstract, Wrap,
  NullAllowed, StaticAttribute, HttpMethod, ResponseFormat,
  BufferManager)
- A member is already defined. Rename this member or use different parameters types. (I think sharpie just named two methods the same
  way, and I just need to change the name of one of them)
- Type byte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong expected. (ApiDefinition uses nuint and nint, I fixed it in changing them for
  ulong and long)

Here is the Binding project with the files ApiDefinition.cs and Structs.cs that I have targeting the *.h:

https://github.com/aroy314/DeezerSDKBinding

I would be thankful if anyone could give me a hint about what is wrong and how to make with project work.